# Hive Query performance tuning

Tags: hadoop, hive, query-optimization

I'm a newbie with hadoop & hive. Can you please suggest if there are any performance tuning steps for Apache Hive running on cloudera 5.2.1 .

what are the tuning parameters in order to improve hive queries performance

Hive version :- Hive 0.13.1-cdh5.2.1

Hive query :-

select    distinct a1.chain_number  chain_number,
                a1.chain_description  chain_description
from      staff.organization_hierarchy a1;

Hive table is created as external with option "STORED AS TEXT FORMAT" and table properties as below :-

After changing below hive setting we have seen 10 sec improvement

set hive.exec.parallel=true;

Can  you please suggest any other setting apart from above to improve hive query performance for the type of query i am using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` to replace the `distinct`,because there will be only 1 reduce job to do the `distinct` job.

Try this

```
 select chain_number, chain_description 
 from staff.organization_hierarchy
 group by chain_number, chain_description
```

If the reduce job number is still very small.You can specific it by using `mapred.reduct.tasks` configure